# Sum values if they are between date range sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to sum values where date is between de creationdate and endDate,, hence ValueEnd.

[image]

For instances the second row, the creationDate is the same as the endDate, so I have to sum the ValuePerDay of this day to the previsou value. So in the column ValueEnd it is 3.4+1.17 = 4.57

I started by calculating the sum from the days where de Difference is 1, like this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), CreationDate,103) CreationDate
    ,CONVERT(CHAR(10), EndDate,103) EndDate
    ,SUM(Values_an) Values_an
    FROM Dat1
    WHERE Difference=1
    GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), CreationDate,103), CONVERT(CHAR(10), EndDate,103), Difference
```

However, I'm having trouble sum the values where the difference if higher than 1. Can someone help me please?

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is not a problem description. What happens when you try that? Why is that wrong?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, if the first rows value for `ValueEnd` is 4.63 (3.5 + 1.13) why is the 2nd rows value not 6.89 ((1.13 * 3) + 3.5)? Where does the 3.5 even come from?

Comment: Actually it does, because if the difference between the endDate and the creationDate is 1, then the value should be the same has Values_an

Comment: @Sofia then why is (in the first row) value_an 3.4 and ValuePerD 3.5? And where is your 1.13 from? Value per day is 3.5, so it should be Difference * ValuePerD, no?

Comment: @Tyron78 you are right. I made a mistake collecting the data. Now it is the same

Comment: @Sofia OK an where does you 1.13 come from? In the first row you have 3.4, in the second row - which matches the date in the first row - yo have 3.5... shouldn't the end value be 3.4 + 3.5?

Comment: @Tyron78 since the second row, has a range of 3 days, then the end value should be value_an + the value of 1 day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, judging by the provided information - and as far as I understood everything right - the following approach might solve your problem:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  CreationDate date,
  EndDate date,
  Value_An decimal(19,4)
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2019-03-01', '2019-03-01', 3.4)
,('2019-03-01', '2019-03-03', 3.5)
,('2019-05-01', '2019-05-01', 3.6)
,('2019-06-01', '2019-06-04', 3.7)

;WITH cteMultiRow AS(
SELECT CreationDate, COUNT(*) cntRows
  FROM @t
  GROUP BY CreationDate
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
),
cte AS(
  SELECT t.*
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CreationDate ORDER BY t.EndDate) AS rn
        ,DATEDIFF(d, t.CreationDate, t.EndDate)+1 AS Difference
        ,CASE WHEN m.CreationDate IS NOT NULL THEN t.Value_An/(DATEDIFF(d, t.CreationDate, t.EndDate)+1) ELSE t.Value_An END AS ValuePerD
    FROM @t t
    LEFT JOIN cteMultiRow m ON t.CreationDate = m.CreationDate
),
cteSums AS(
  SELECT c.CreationDate, SUM(c.ValuePerD) AS ValuePerD
    FROM cte c
    GROUP BY c.CreationDate
)
SELECT c.CreationDate, c.EndDate, c.Value_An, c.Difference, c.ValuePerD, ISNULL(s.ValuePerD, c.Value_An) AS ValueEnd
  FROM cte c
  LEFT JOIN cteSums s ON c.CreationDate = s.CreationDate AND c.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!